# Excel-like plugin to work with Durandal Breeze and Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal, handsontable

I need to build an SPA with Durandal Breeze and Knockout, but for data entry I need to show sections similar to excel.

I had found a nice plugin [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) this in appearance is exactly for me, but I don't know if this plugin is compatible with Durandal Breeze and Knockout for:

- Enter data in the cells
- Move easily between cells with arrow keys
- Copy and paste values from/to excel
- Export data to Excel/Pdf
- Compatible in mobile devices

Comment: "What's the best" questions generally don't result in productive discussion here: be more specific about your needs.

Comment: On Handsontable's [issues board](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues) there have never been a issue about Durandal/Knockout/Breeze and I have never tried it with those libraries. 

I can only say: Please try it out yourself and let me know on GitHub if you run into any problems.

Comment: I will try with hansontable and of course I will report errors on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't make a comment and this is by no means a complete answer but
here is a first attempt I worked up.
for some reason you have to click the screen for the grid to appear :
    define(['knockout'], function (ko) {
        var ctor = function () {

```
    this.columns = 4
    this.rows = 4
    this.data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 92, 93, 94], [7, 8, 9,]]
    this.init = function (view) {


    }

};

ctor.prototype.attached = function () {
    $('#example').handsontable({
        data: this.data,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true
    });
};
ctor.prototype.activate = function (view) {

};

ctor.prototype.binding=function(view)
{
   // this.init(view);
}
return ctor;
});
```

Comment: this will work fine (without clicking the screen) if there is no input transition...